# Проблема с кодировкой PDF

Tags: python, ubuntu, кодировка, pdf

Всем привет!

Делаю проект на джанго. Есть определенная страница, которая конвертится в PDF при помощи этого кода:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa

class Render:

@staticmethod
def render(path: str, params: dict):
    template = get_template(path)
    html = template.render(params)
    response = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), response)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(response.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Error Rendering PDF", status=400)
```

Разработка велась на Windows. Была проблема с кодировкой, пофиксилось добавлением файла font.ttf с кириллическим шрифтом в папку проекта и указанием его в стиле:

```
<style>
  @font-face { 
    font-family: 'Font';
    src: url("../font.ttf");
  }
  .table {
    font-family: "Font";
  }
</style>
```

Когда начал разворачивать проект на ubuntu снова столкнулся с этой проблемой.

Переместил файл шрифта в **static/fonts**, изменил код на:

```
<style>
  @font-face { 
    font-family: 'Font';
    src: url("{% static "fonts/font.ttf" %}");
  }
  .table {
    font-family: "Font";
  }
</style>
```

Файл скачивается по урлу, но проблему это не решило.
Также пробовал менять кодировку в функции render класса Render в строке:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), response)
```

Все-равно кириллические символы отображаются неверно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было просто поменять с UTF-8 на UTF-16